# Getting JSON records line by line from a file, in python

Tags: python, json, file

I am working with JSON files in python. I have keys in a list, for each key I retrieve a JSON record, which I store in a file. Each JSON record contains that key inside.

In a separate process, I need to read that JSON file and retrieve each record, get key and do something else.

The problem is I cannot read JSON lines from file I stored this way:

```
dataFile = open(output_file, "w")
for line in keys_list:
   json_line = fetch_json_str(line)
   data = simplejson.loads(json_line)
   dataFile.write(simplejson.dumps(data, sort_keys = True))
```

It reads all into one line, and the length of returned list is 0, len(json_lines).

```
  json_lines = [line.strip() for line in open(tmp_load_file)]
  for line in json_lines
      data = simplejson.loads(simplejson.dumps(line))
```

What do I do wrong? Is there any way to get back JSON lines without changing the way I stored them, because that will call for re-processing all the json files I stored this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line separator when you write the json string

```
dataFile.write(simplejson.dumps(data, sort_keys = True) + '\n')
```

Otherwise, you just get all of the json records in a single line and the json parser can't figure it out.